# Need help making this sql work?

Tags: mysql

Here is the sql i am working with to create a report.

```
Select dw_crime_fact.no_of_crimes, dw_area_dim.area_desc, dw_time_dim.year,            dw_crime_type_dim.crime_type_desc
FROM dw_crime_fact, dw_area_dim, dw_time_dim, dw_crime_type_dim
WHERE dw_crime_fact.fk2_area_id = dw_area_dim.area_id
AND dw_crime_fact.fk1_time_id = dw_time_dim.time_id
AND dw_crime_fact.fk3_crime_type_id = dw_crime_type_dim.crime_type_id
AND dw_area_dim.area_id = '9' 
AND dw_crime_type_dim.crime_type_id = '120'
ORDER BY dw_time_dim.year
```

Where i have include the last two and statements

AND dw_area_dim.area_id = '9' 
AND dw_crime_type_dim.crime_type_id = '120'

I need to add several more ids in to these so for :

area_id i need it to come from '9' and '10'
and 
crime_type_id needs to come from '80' , '90', '120' and '200'

I have tried making more and/or statements but they appear as no data found.

Please help me to solve this, any additional information needed just ask.

Answer (score 1):

just use an `IN` clause for multiple values.

```
AND dw_area_dim.area_id IN( '9', '10')
AND dw_crime_type_dim.crime_type_id IN ('80', '90', '120', '200')
```

By the way, I would rewrite your whole query to

```
Select 
crime.no_of_crimes, 
area.area_desc, 
timed.year, 
crime_type.crime_type_desc
FROM dw_crime_fact crime
join dw_area_dim area on area.area_id = crime.fk2_area_id
join dw_time_dime timed on timed.time_id = crime.fk1_time_id
join dw_crime_type_dim crime_type on crime_type.crime_type_id = crime.fk3_crime_type_id
WHERE 
area.area_id IN( '9', '10')
AND crime_type.crime_type_id IN ('80', '90', '120', '200')
ORDER BY timed.year
```

Comment: It now saying there is a missing expression :/

Comment: Select dw_crime_fact.no_of_crimes, dw_area_dim.area_desc, dw_time_dim.year, dw_crime_type_dim.crime_type_desc
FROM dw_crime_fact, dw_area_dim, dw_time_dim, dw_crime_type_dim
WHERE dw_crime_fact.fk2_area_id = dw_area_dim.area_id
AND dw_crime_fact.fk1_time_id = dw_time_dim.time_id
AND dw_crime_fact.fk3_crime_type_id = dw_crime_type_dim.crime_type_id
AND dw_area_dim.area_id IN = ('9' ,'10')
AND dw_crime_type_dim.crime_type_id IN = ('80', '90', '120' ,'200')
ORDER BY dw_time_dim.year

Comment: @user3075072 - look **closely** at Raphael's code.  You have `IN = `, which is *not* what he suggested.

Comment: it's not `IN = (` it's just `IN (`

Comment: Hi, it saying that the code you have re written is not properly ended?

Comment: @user3075072, as a newbie, since this solved your question, be sure to give credit by up-checking and clicking the checkmark next to the answer so others know it is a solved question.